# Pre populate text box in 3rd party website - c#

Tags: c#, javascript, web, external

this is my first time on Stackoverflow so any help will be appriciated.

I need a c#/js code to prepopulate two textbox on a 3rd party website ("https://webc.rbc.com/cda-cgi/clientcgi.exe?action=browserCert")

I can not send a query string as I dont have any controll over this site.

Thanks in advance
-Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following link with the appropriate fill-ins:

https://webc.rbc.com/cda-cgi/clientcgi.exe?action=browserCert&refNo=12&authcode=34

I just tried using that and it populates the fields for me in Chrome and IE.  It looks like the cgi script on their side is set up to take these inputs.

Comment: I think that they had to have it set up in their CGI script for this to work like that.