# How to Pre-populate text box on a third party website?

Tags: hyperlink, textbox, web

I have a client that has an affiliate code and wants to create a link that pre-populates his affiliate code into the text box on the affiliate page.

After some Googling I found: [Pre populate text box in 3rd party website - c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098751/pre-populate-text-box-in-3rd-party-website-c-sharp)

Which is exactly what my client wants to do but the issue I am running into is that the affiliate page has a video popup that you have to close and for some reason that is making it not work. I need help figuring out how to pre-populate the affiliate code: 144 into http://reallyfunnyhypnosis.com/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A browser will not allow you to do that; it's basically XSS and they are designed to prevent it.

The trick you've linked to relies on passing correclty named parameters into the URL that are interpreted by the server. This is lucky and depends on the server-side handling of those parameters. Bad luck for you that the site you're willing to automatically fill-in doesn't work this way (it's not the video popup that makes it not work). If you don't have control over the server there's nothing you can do about it.

Even if you tried to put the target site inside an iframe and tried to manipulate its fields with javascript, it would fail as browsers do not allow cross-site scripting (XSS), that is: they don't allow scripts from a domain to manipulate content from another domain.